# Drop into irb when debugging in Aptana 3

Tags: ruby, aptana, ruby-debug, rdebug

I am new to ruby and Aptana (I have used eclipse before) I was wondering if when debugging in Aptana we can drop into irb to play around with things with current values set. For example doing Java dev in eclipse on a breakpoint you can open Window -> Show View -> Display and start executing Java code with all objects having their current state. Is there a similar thing for debugging ruby apps in Aptana 3?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature wasn't implemented in Studio 3.0, but is scheduled for 3.0.2. Here's the ticket for the work: https://aptana.lighthouseapp.com/projects/35272/tickets/2122-port-display-view-fro-ruby-debugging-from-radrails-2x

You can try it out via our nightly builds. See here for the instructions on getting that: http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Changing+the+Update+Type#

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start an IRB session at runtime try [Pry](http://github.com/banister/pry). Also Check out the [blog post](http://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/turning-irb-on-its-head-with-pry/)